# Generated Quantities in STAN: negative binomial rng

Tags: self-study, prediction, negative-binomial-distribution, stan

I'm working with a Negative binomial regression in STAN.

I would like to make predictions on a test set, but looking at the reference I can't find a negative_binomial random number generator.

Is there any way to do so without saving mean and overdispersion distributions and sampling from them in R ?

Comment: I think you need to add the self-study tag.

Comment: Also since you are mainly looking for information on two software packages (STAN and R), the question is off topic for this site.

Comment: Ok, I'll move to stackoverflow and add the self study tag there, thank you for raising my awareness about this site :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Stan User's Guide (2.14.0)](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.14.0/stan-reference-2.14.0.pdf), it appears you should be able to generate samples from a negative binomial using:

`neg_binomial_rng(real alpha, real beta)`

You can draw from this distribution on each step of your chain by including it in the normal manner in your `generated quantities` block, e.g.

`generated quantities {
  vector[N] y_rep;
  for (n in 1:N) {
    y_rep[n] = neg_binomial_rng(alpha, beta);
  }
}`

Where `alpha` and `beta` are your parameter estimates at each step, and `N` is the total number of samples to generate - specified as input to the `data` block.

Comment: Why can't I find things on the Stan reference remains a mistery. Thank you!!

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini  No problem. FWIW, you can also specify using alternate parameterizations `neg_binomial_2_rng(real mu, real phi)` and `neg_binomial_2_log_rng(real eta, real phi)` which take precision and logged parameters, respectively.

Comment: Yep, actually I used the one with the overdispersion and log, thank you again!